# How do I install my wireless network drivers from .tar.gz file?

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom, tar

I've been looking and searching for a while now but can't figure this out.
I've downloaded Linux 64-bit drivers for my Broadcom wireless internal adapter in my laptop.
The file was in .tar.gaz, so far I've understood that you have to extract it an go on from there, so I have, now I can't figure out how to actually install it.
I doubt it's as easy as just moving over the files to my c:\ drive.

The files structure is like this:
/lib/
/src/
Makefile

Notice, I installed Ubuntu TODAY, so I have no idea what I'm doing.
The Makefile file has install commands at the bottom when opened with Notepad++, but it does not make sense to me.
Here's the info from the file:

```
#Check GCC version so we can apply -Wno-date-time if supported.  GCC >= 4.9
empty:=
space:= $(empty) $(empty)
GCCVERSIONSTRING := $(shell expr `$(CC) -dumpversion`)
#Create version number without "."
GCCVERSION := $(shell expr `echo $(GCCVERSIONSTRING)` | cut -f1 -d.)
GCCVERSION += $(shell expr `echo $(GCCVERSIONSTRING)` | cut -f2 -d.)
GCCVERSION += $(shell expr `echo $(GCCVERSIONSTRING)` | cut -f3 -d.)
# Make sure the version number has at least 3 decimals
GCCVERSION += 00
# Remove spaces from the version number
GCCVERSION := $(subst $(space),$(empty),$(GCCVERSION))
# Crop the version number to 3 decimals.
GCCVERSION := $(shell expr `echo $(GCCVERSION)` | cut -b1-3)
GE_49 := $(shell expr `echo $(GCCVERSION)` \>= 490)

EXTRA_CFLAGS :=

ifeq ($(APIFINAL),CFG80211)
  EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DUSE_CFG80211
  $(info Using CFG80211 API)
endif

ifeq ($(APIFINAL),WEXT)
  EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DUSE_IW
  $(info Using Wireless Extension API)
endif

obj-m              += wl.o

wl-objs            :=
wl-objs            += src/shared/linux_osl.o
wl-objs            += src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o
wl-objs            += src/wl/sys/wl_iw.o
wl-objs            += src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.o

EXTRA_CFLAGS       += -I$(src)/src/include -I$(src)/src/common/include
EXTRA_CFLAGS       += -I$(src)/src/wl/sys -I$(src)/src/wl/phy -I$(src)/src/wl/ppr/include
EXTRA_CFLAGS       += -I$(src)/src/shared/bcmwifi/include
#EXTRA_CFLAGS       += -DBCMDBG_ASSERT -DBCMDBG_ERR
ifeq "$(GE_49)" "1"
EXTRA_CFLAGS       += -Wno-date-time
endif

EXTRA_LDFLAGS      := $(src)/lib/wlc_hybrid.o_shipped

KBASE              ?= /lib/modules/`uname -r`
KBUILD_DIR         ?= $(KBASE)/build
MDEST_DIR          ?= $(KBASE)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless

# Cross compile setup.  Tool chain and kernel tree, replace with your own.
CROSS_TOOLS        = /path/to/tools
CROSS_KBUILD_DIR   = /path/to/kernel/tree

all:
    KBUILD_NOPEDANTIC=1 make -C $(KBUILD_DIR) M=`pwd`

cross:
    KBUILD_NOPEDANTIC=1 make CROSS_COMPILE=${CROSS_TOOLS} -C $(CROSS_KBUILD_DIR) M=`pwd`

clean:
    KBUILD_NOPEDANTIC=1 make -C $(KBUILD_DIR) M=`pwd` clean

install:
    install -D -m 755 wl.ko $(MDEST_DIR)
```

Comment: what is your device and why are you trying to install a driver this way? Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes, I am using Ubuntu on a Lenovo Thinkpad Edge E320. I'm trying to do so because there is no other way, at least from what I've read at the Ubuntu documentation page "Wireless network troubleshooter" (which I was linked to after checking my adapter PCI ID).

Comment: Also, the "duplicate" said mine was a "special case" that it "Uses bcma and brcmsmac driver combination. Required firmware is installed by default in the package linux-firmware."

Comment: Now the wireless connection dropped... ugh...

Comment: And did you install the [linux-firmware package for your version of Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-firmware&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all)?

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure you do the following things in Ubuntu and not in Windows!**

Open up a terminal by pressing (at the same time) "Ctrl" + "Alt" + "t".

Tell us which version of Ubuntu you are using: `uname -a`.

Now find out what wireless card your computer has: Type `sudo lspci -i network` and post the output here.

Also post the output of `sudo lshw -C network`.

Since you downloaded a driver, I assume that you have a wired network with internet connection.

Update your system: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Then make sure you have standard drivers installed (as Elder Geek said in his comment): `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware`.